# Win 7 and ODBC with 64 bit

Tags: asp.net, 64-bit, odbc

I am developing an ASP.NET Application and am trying to use the 64-bit driver version of ODBC on my 64 bit win 7 machine, because the deployment server has Windows Server 2008, which is naturally in 64 bit, since Microsoft decided not to make a 32 bit version afaik.

The first issue was an `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException` **"ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application"**. Despite the fact, that I am developing on a 64 bit operation system, the compiler seems to have decided to compile for 32 bit. After some research I changed the target platform to x64 in every of my (own) assemblies. I am using NHibernate and Spring.Net, but I read somewhere that 64 bit is no problem for NHibernate. I did not check Spring.Net yet. The compilation began.

I got some warnings that quite every .net assembly is built for another platform, but I read somewhere again that I can ignore these warning and the application should run just fine because the runtime (or compiler?) will figure out the right assembly.

So I tested the application right away and was rewarded with an `System.BadImageFormatException` (wrong format). It was again an exception concerning 32/64 bit issues although every one of my assemblies is compiled as 64 bit.

I am slowly starting to hate 64 bit. Seriously. Is it that difficult to build an 64 bit application on an 64 bit operation system for a 64 bit server with 64 bit drivers?

Does anybody have a solution or have experience with this issue? I found many workarounds with using 32 bit, but that is not an option here. It has to be a 64 bit solution.

Nevertheless I will continue trying for myself to solve this. I will write any progress here.

**Update:**
Spring.Net seems to be just fine on 64 bit since the assembly is "dynamically compiled at runtime to the native machine architecture".

Answer (score 1):

i fought with this same error for several hours. My environment was slightly different, but the error was the same. I was using SSRS, Report Builder 3 and SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Win Server 2008 R2 x64 Box
I could create connections and test them successfully in SSRS, but when i would use them, i got the error above. It was resolved when i created a 32bit DSN of the same name and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to go other way: If I don't need any native in-proc DLLs, I use AnyCPU. So final program can be used on both x86 and x64. If I need native in-proc DLLs, I always chose x86 32bit version, because it is much easier to make it work correctly, and IMPORTANTLY I don't need any 64bit features. So why 64bit version? I just go to IIS configuration and setup my asp.net application to run in 32bit mode.

For example my current deveopment environment is fully 64bit and works perfectly. But my production server is setup to host my app in 32bit mode. It works perfectly, no 64bit issues. I apologize if this answer is not good for you, but I really never needed 64bit stuff in my asp.net applications.

update: I use 32bit IIS on production server. I am not sure if it is possible to setup asp.net as 32bit in 64bit IIS.

Comment: Unfortunately it is about compatibility between the components (application <-> 64 bit odbc driver) rather than the 64 bit stuff. But i read about the 32 bit mode, but i rather want to think about that as my last resort.